# Using fakeAsync in tests results in error with Angular 4 and Zone.js

Tags: angular, webpack, jasmine, zone.js

I'm using Angular `4.3.1` and `zone.js` `0.8.14` and I'm running my tests, with `karma` and `webpack` and came across this weird error in my tests whenever I'm using `fakeAsync` and tick for time-related tests.

The test case:

```
it('should call the function which is given as parameter', fakeAsync(() => {
  autoRefreshService.start();
  expect(spyFn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  tick(1);
  expect(spyFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

The test invoking file:

```
require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
const context = (require as any).context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().map(context);
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.12.5) CallbackRepeaterService start should not start if no callback set FAILED
    TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
        at Object.<anonymous> (src/test.ts:25139:49)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (src/test.ts:86299:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (src/test.ts:88697:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (src/test.ts:86298:32)
        at Zone.run (src/test.ts:86049:43)
        at Object.<anonymous> (src/test.ts:88992:34)
        at ZoneQueueRunner.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute (src/test.ts:89020:42)
```

The error message must be related to `fakeAsync`, because if I remove it, it doesn't complain.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: It's not clear what's going on. I would suggest to check first what's Object.<anonymous>, since you're the only person who can do this.

Answer (score 5):

So the problem was I needed to add `import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';` to the testing entry file.